# Spring Boot - Use Spring Data JPA and JdbcTemplate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I'm using spring Data jpa  and jdbctemplate in my API.
At the beginning of the transaction in my service method (serviceMethod) I'm using @Transactional annotation without any propogation or isolation set. So it uses the default values.

Within the serviceMethod I'm calling my method updateTableA. Which in turn uses jdbctemplate to update a table, tableA and returns to the serviceMethod.

Within the serviceMethod I'm creating an instance of a spring data entity mapped to tableA called tableAEntity.
But while reading the entity I'm getting the old data instead of the data that was updated in the method updateTableA.

Is there any configuration that I need to do?

I'm using a hikari datasource.

I've tried introducing read uncomitted but then realised that's for reading data committed from other sessions. But I want to read committed within my transaction.
If I'm reading the data from the table using jdbctemplate I'm able to get the updated value. But unfortunately, I still have to use the spring data entity